# Maximal ideal with respect to property that it does not contain an ideal A

Tags: ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

let A=($a1, a2, .... ,an$) be a non-zero finitely generated ideal of R. 
Prove that there is an ideal B which is maximal with respect to property that it does not contain A.

I don't know how to proceed. Maybe by Zorn's lemma.
If I define order by containment of ideals. Then in a chain what will be the maximal element. 
If ∪J { J ∈ Chain } how to check that A is not contained inside ∪J.

Answer (score 3):

You are right, the idea, is the Zorn, consider the set $J$ of ideals which does not contain $A$, let $(B_i)$ be a family of well ordered (by the inclusion) element of $J$, $B=\cup_{i\in I}B_i$ is the sup. Suppose that $B$ contains $A$, $a_j\in B_{i_j}$ let $k=sup(i_1,...,i_n)$, since $B_{i_j}\subset B_k$, $a_1,...,a_n\in B_k$ contradiction. Thus $J$ has a maximum element.

Comment: can you please explain last line saying k = sup(i1, ....in )

Comment: since $J$ is totally ordered, $k$ exists.

Comment: got it. Thank you !